# Memory Issues in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

In my App I am downloading images from the server of full size **640 * 960** for iPhone and saving it in the `core data`. After some time I am getting **"Receive memory Warning"** message on console, as the app size is getting increased and images get unloaded from the Screen. I don’t know how to manage the receive memory warning issue, as the app get crashed after receiving messages 4 or 5 times.

Comment: I think you need to remove the cached memory as you are downloading the images :)

Comment: Also it's not a good idea to save images in coredata, it slow since all the images get load in memory. Why not just save the image to the doucment directory and same the file name in the coredata object.

Comment: hi wolvorin.I know that  but does not know how to clear the cache memory as i have to keep all the images in core data once the images get downloaded .so that user can see it at once..

Comment: hi rckoenes i know its a option but i have saved it in core data because i have to show particular image for a particular screen in a particular condition .how can i manage that if i saved it in document directory.

Comment: Instead of storing the image as a blob in core data, save the path to the image in the documents directory. Step by step is something like this:
1) download the image and save it in the documents directory
2) save the file URL in your core data store as a string
3) when you need the image, use the file url you saved earlier to load the image from your documents directory.

Comment: Thanks Matias For suggestion but i m using download picture operation for downloading images .and it is impossible to know when image get downloaded so at which point i saved it in documents directory..

Comment: How are you downloading the image?

Comment: hi melita thanks for ur perfect suggestion i have done that but still i m getting memory waring in my other app when regulary picking images from library using imagepickercontroller.is this anything to do with imagepickercontroller.

Answer (score 0):

I won't be able to tell you the reason with this much detail. But I can tell you a way with which you can try finding your issue. You can use **Instruments** to find your leaks or memory hogging.

- In your Xcode Project, goto "Product" -> click on "Profile". Instruments window will open.
- Click on "leaks". Now explore your applications and instruments will tell you the exact line of code where your leaks are coming from.